# Creating a JAR file and running on Raspberry PI

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

This is a very common question and there are chances that this might be marked as Duplicate, but even after reviewing a lot of answers and posts from stackoverflow and other communities, the problem just doesn't solve.

I have created a Project in my NetBeans IDE 7.3 and I Build the Project to get the JAR file by pressing SHIFT+F11. The next step, I perform is through WinSCP I copy the JAR file from my Windows Machine to the directory (/home/pi) in Raspberry PI.
Now, I am in the directory in my Raspberry PI where the JAR file is present and in the terminal I run the command

```
java -jar ProjectFinal.jar
```

I get the error "Could not find or load main class".

The contents of my JAR are as shown below (in the form of directories):
lib (contains all the libraries)
META-INF (contains a MANIFEST.MF file and the contents looks fine) and the contents are shown below:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_17-b02 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: projectfinal.ProjectFinal**
```

and finally projectfinal (contains all the class files). I tried to change the contents of the MANIFEST.MF file by following [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). But this couldn't help me either.
Please suggest me any ideas that could get me out of this. It could be really helpful. I can share the code if it is needed.
I am using JRE version 7.
Any questions/inputs/ideas is deeply appreciated.

**Please help.**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi Everyone, 
I found the solution over here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946394/how-to-create-executable-jar-file-with-netbeans. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about NetBeans but Eclipse IDE has an option to export into a "Runnable JAR File" instead of a normal JAR file.
I had the same issue and it solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks you. It worked for me. For all the people who are using NetBeans, you can follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946394/how-to-create-executable-jar-file-with-netbeans. It helped a lot.

Comment: Can be executed on Pi from terminal `java -jar path/to/jar/Name.jar`

Answer (score 0):

If not then follow this:

> The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last
>   line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or
>   carriage return.

Comment: Yup. It has a new line and fortunately I found a link which helped me. Thanks for your input. Appreciate it.